# Sorting MySQL results by calculated distance (distance not stored in DB)

Tags: php, android, mysql, sorting, geolocation

I have "Places" stored in a database and I am using PHP to access them. What I want to do is to return all Places sorted by distance relative to a certain place.

This place will be dynamic from an Android application, i.e. I want to display all places closest to the user's location.

What would be the best way to do this? Would it be effective/efficient to retrieve ALL places in PHP into an array, calculate the distance for each place, and then sort that array by distance? Or is there an easier/faster way to accomplish what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in SQL, by calculating the distance on the fly. This is a rough approximation of the distance between stored `lat`/`lon` fields and supplied `$lat`/`$lon`

```
$dlat = "(`lat`-$lat)";
$dlon = "(`lon`-$lon)*".cos($lat*3.1415/180);
$dist_sql = "$dlat*$dlat+$dlon*$dlon";
$sql = "IF(`lat` IS NULL,1e20,$dist_sql)";
```

then use `$sql` as you would use any other field, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY $sql ASC
```

This is far from perfect but should get you started at least.

The `cos()` comes in because one degree of longitude is less distance as the (absolute) latitude increases.

To get from `$sql` to an actual value in km, divide by 90 and multiply by 10000 km. (again: very rough approximation!)

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks, didn't know this could be done in SQL. I was hoping there was a better way. Thanks for the start, I'll work off of it.

Answer (score 0):

If each location in the db has lat/lon fields then do the distance calculation in the db. The following stored procedure would need some tweaking to suit your db because we do not know the schema - but it assumes a table called `places` with a field with the location's latitude and a field with the longitude.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spNearestPlaces`(IN `_latitude` double, IN `_longitude` double, IN `_radius` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
proc:begin
    declare strsql varchar(10000);
    declare lat double default 0;
    declare lng double default 0;
    declare radius float default 0;
    declare earth_radius integer default 0;
    declare lon1 float;
    declare lat1 float;
    declare lon2 float;
    declare lat2 float;



    set @lat=_latitude;
    set @lng=_longitude;

    set @radius=cast(_radius as unsigned);
    set @earth_radius=3956;

    set @lon1 = @lng - @radius/ceil( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * 69 );
    set @lon2 = @lng + @radius/ceil( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * 69 );
    set @lat1 = @lat - ( @radius/69 );
    set @lat2 = @lat + ( @radius/69 );




    set @strsql=concat("select
            p.`id`,
            p.`latitude`,
            p.`longitude`,
            ROUND( @earth_radius * 2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( (@lat - p.`latitude`) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(@lat * pi()/180) * COS(p.`latitude` * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((@lng - p.`longitude`) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ),2) AS 'distance'
            from `places` p
            where   
                    p.`latitude` between @lat1 and @lat2
                    and 
                    p.`longitude` between @lon1 and @lon2
            having `distance` <= @radius 
            order by `distance`;");

    prepare stmt from @strsql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
end
```

You would call the stored procedure from php like:-

```
$lat=56.564;
$lng=-2.5465;
$radius=5;

call `spNearestPlaces`($lat,$lng,$radius);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I will check this out. As of right now my table does not have Lat/Long but I can easily add these in if needed